# XSL :count consecutive attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file like follows:

```
<Query>
<Rows>
    <Row Pd="1"></Row>
    <Row Pd="1"></Row>
    <Row Pd="0"></Row>
    <Row Pd="0"></Row>
    <Row Pd="0"></Row>
    <Row Pd="0"></Row>
    <Row Pd="1"></Row>
    <Row Pd="1"></Row>
    <Row Pd="1"></Row>
    <Row Pd="1"></Row>
    <Row Pd="1"></Row>
    <Row Pd="1"></Row>
    <Row Pd="1"></Row>
    <Row Pd="0"></Row>
    <Row Pd="0"></Row>
    <Row Pd="0"></Row>
    <Row Pd="1"></Row>
    <Row Pd="1"></Row>
    <Row Pd="1"></Row>
</Rows>
</Query>
```

This is basically an ordered list of items with a "Pd" attribute (value= 0 or 1).
I need to display the following results :

> 1. total number of rows with Pd=1,
> 2. number of latest consecutive rows with Pd=1 (0 if latest Pd=0)
> 3. largest serie of consecutive rows with Pd=1

I managed to get 1. and 2. but failed to achieve 3.

My solution for 1 & 2 (XSLT 1.0):

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <div> 
        <h1>total # of Pd1 : <xsl:value-of select="sum(//Row/@Pd)"/></h1>
        <h1># of consecutive Pd1: <xsl:apply-templates/> </h1>
    </div> 
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//Row[not(following-sibling::Row[1]/@Pd=self::Row/@Pd)][1]"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(self::Row[1]/@Pd|preceding-sibling::Row/@Pd)"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For the above-quoted xml, expected results should be :

> 1. 12
> 2. 2
> 3. 7

Any help for the solution to question 3 is welcomed (as well as improvements to the other solutions provided)

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0 and that way `xsl:for-each-group select="//Row" group-adjacent="@Pd"`?

Comment: Unfortunately, only XSLT 1.0... even though, grouping is one thing, getting the longest sequence among those groups wouldn't be that easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way in XSLT 1.0 to do number 3, although it won't be pleasant (especially because XSLT 1.0 doesn't have the `max` command). First define a key like so...

```
<xsl:key name="rows" match="Row" use="count(preceding-sibling::Row[@Pd != current()/@Pd])" />
```

Then, to get the largest series of consecutive rows with Pd=1 you can do this

```
<h1>
    <xsl:text>Largest serie of consecutive rows with Pd=1: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="//Row[@Pd='1']">
        <xsl:sort select="count(key('rows', count(preceding-sibling::Row[@Pd != current()/@Pd]))[@Pd='1'])" order="descending" />
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(key('rows', count(preceding-sibling::Row[@Pd != current()/@Pd]))[@Pd='1'])" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</h1>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a sample input where it doesn't work? I tested your current input at http://xsltransform.net/a9GixJ and the total 7 as expected.Thanks

Comment: I just tested it. Output is OK for the provided serie (1100001111111000111)->7. But, with different datasets, results are wrong : (1100001110111000111)->6 (should be 3). I'm not enough fluent in the xpath syntax to explain why...

Comment: I have corrected the issue. It was failing because it was also including the maximum length of 0's too.

Comment: Still failing... (1100001111011000111)->3 (instead of 4)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I didn't copy in all amended lines in my answer. I have amended it a second time.